# Entity Framework Issue while working with source control

Tags: c#, svn, entity-framework-4, t4

We are working with VS2012, Entity Framework 4 db-first on SVN Source Control.

We have an issue with Entity Framework when we want to make changes in the database.
the programmer that uploaded the EF model to the source control can change the db and after we update our version it workes fine.
but if one of the other programmers changes the db and commit his changes the EF model corrupts and we must that the first programmer insert the db changes to make it work.

In his solution the CodeGenerationStrategy property is T4 and in our soultion the CodeGenerationStrategy property is None.

How can we fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: what gets corrupted? Use a diff tool to see the changes

Comment: when we update the entity model after creating/updating tables in the db, and than commit changes - the entity model extensions that we created our gone. but if the first programmer updates the entity model and commit changes it all works.

Comment: I still have no clue what fails.Create a demo project were you can repro this and create a screencast of the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we upgraded to vs2015 and it fix this.